# moving one directory backward in R path

Tags: r

Let's say this is the working directory where my R script is residing:

```
C:/Users/Indrajeet Patil/Dropbox/Study 1/Data analysis
```

I know how to create a new directory inside the **current** working directory-

```
dir.create(path = paste(getwd(), '/Results', sep = ''))
```

What I am struggling with is how to tell `R` to move **one folder backward** and create a new directory. So, in this example, I want to create a new folder inside the folder `Study 1` and call it `Results`.

Comment: Use `../` to go one up. No need to paste together the path anyways, the new directory is normally already in the working directory (I believe).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To go back once you need to add `..` to the beginning of the path as in

```
dir.create(path = '../Results')
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I do the same with `getwd` function. That is, I want to get the path to folder one step backward from cwd by using `base::getwd`. `getwd(..)` doesn't work.

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil, `dirname(getwd())` does that, although it shouldn't be really necessary.

Comment: Awesome!! That's exactly what I needed.